# Using Window print makes app hang after closing tab

Tags: javascript, html

I used framework CI 4 on my application. I've used `window.print()` + `window.open` and a new tab appeared for print. But the problem is that after I closed the Window print tab, my app hanged up/switched to white screen.

If I use `cancel` button instead of closing `window.print` tab, no issue occured.

Edit :
I've created simple code in JSFiddle (with same issue)

https://jsfiddle.net/L2t5kefb/

Comment: Does that always happen or happened just once?

Comment: @WebDevLearner always happen

Comment: Couldn't recreate it... Can you check in another browser, within your device?

Comment: Which browser are you using? The print dialog has no other way to be closed other than the cancel button

Comment: @WebDevLearner, i am using window open and new tab will appear, so there is close button on top right. I tried chrome and IE edge both and tried in other device still same

Comment: I put jsfiddle on my post. After i click test print button and close then click test alert button, alert dialog not appear

Comment: @AjithGopim did u try the jsfiddle with my scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been looking similar issue on internet, seems like `window.print` on new window (`window.open`) blocks javascript after close(x) instead of cancel button. In fact, I didn't come across any issues about this a few weeks ago. Maybe the current browser (chrome / edge) has a new update and this problem is appear